# Story-id: mining town with re-animated and remote controlled dead people used as robot-labor

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots, undead, remote-control

This is short story (maybe short novella) I read in a short-story collection in the mid to late 80's.
Back then I was in my teens and I found the whole concept really creepy.
It left an impression on me to this day.
So I really like to re-read that story and see how I react to it now.
I don't really remember the story-line itself, but a fair number of details about the unusual setting.
Hopefully that is enough for someone to recognize this.

The setting is a mining operation on a remote planet.
The miners spend most of their free time in a mining-town that has bars, gambling dens and brothels.
It has a bit of a "wild-west western" feel to it.

What is special about this setting is that there are re-animated dead people used as robot-workers in the mines.
They are remote-controlled by operators. Each operator controlling several of these 'zombies'.
(Note: I can't recall what they were called in the story.
I use the term zombies for lack of a better word.)
There are female zombies as well. They are put to work in house-keeping, factory work and as entertainment in the brothels in the town.

The control-link is supposed to be one-way, but some operators get remnant memories from the zombies.
This can lead to mental issues for the operators, but this is kept under wraps by the mining company.

Main character is a miner, another character is a female operator.
I'm not sure about this but I vaguely seem to recall that the main characters wife (or girlfriend) died and the female operator is the one controlling the dead wife.

Another thing I'm not sure of (I may be conflating this with something entirely else):
The mining operating is some big corporation that offers 20 or 30 year assignments to this mining-planet, including shipping to/from the planet.
If you die before your time is up, the company has the right to repurpose your body as a zombie, so they still get the promised 20 or 30 years of labor out of you.

Note: This is not "Override" by George R.R. Martin, even though some aspects match.

Comment: Note that the other "Corpse Handlers" stories by Martin ("Meathouse Man" and "Nobody Leaves New Pittsburg") also don't seem to match the notable points here, which include leakage back from the corpses (they don't have brains to leak) and female handlers.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for confirming the other 2 Martin stories don't match either. I have only read Override (which also came up as a possible match when I previewed my question before posting), but never read the other 2.